# Meteor and React: Template events

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm playing around with Meteor and [react-meteor](https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor). However, I can't seem to grok how the template event-handling works when using react (if it even does).

index.html:

```
<head>
  <title>reactjs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> FormTest}}
</body>
```

lib/components/testform.jsx:

```
var FormTest = ReactMeteor.createClass({
  templateName: "FormTest",
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="my-button">My byutton</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

index.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.FormTest.events({
    "click .my-button": function (event, template) {
      alert("My button was clicked!");
    }
  });
}
```

I get nothing.

Is there something wrong with my code or my approach? If approach, what would be the proper way to handle events?

Comment: does u have the java scipt installed??? try with `My BUTTON> intead of My byutton``` hope this workng for yuo also is `class` not className

Answer (score 3):

If you add an event handler here:

```
<button className="my-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>My button</button>
```

You can then do this in your testform.jsx file:

```
handleClick: function(e) {
        if (Meteor.isClient) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("My button was clicked");
        }
}
```

I'm also testing React with Meteor, but this seems to work.

Comment: This does work, but I was hoping to use the meteor events listener as it seems to be better suited to handling form data/events. i.e. in your example, how would you go about getting form data? This method doesn't seem to supply anything other than `SyntheticMouseEvent` which doesn't carry related info (see: `console.log(e)` in `handleClick`). Thanks.

Comment: To get the values from the form field, you can use `refs` and then access the component's DOM node directly using `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput)`. You can read more about refs [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute).